# Create Bluetooth Hotspot while connected to Wifi

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, thinkpad, hot-spot

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

My school has provided me with a ThinkPad L420, that (probably physically) cannot connect to wifi.
More information about the ThinkPad:

- it came preinstalled with Windows
- I am not allowed to install anything to the local ssd
- I will use the computer by plugging in an external SSD to boot into Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (basically I booted into an Ubuntu Stick and selected the external SSD to install to, and as the location of the bootloader)
- on Windows the Wifi doesn't work, there is no option for it in the menu. Windows Error analysis tells me that I should use Ethernet.
- In the Ubuntu Live ISO and in the installed version of Ubuntu on the SSD is no option for Wifi in the Quick Settings menu, and not even in the real settings menu
- The loan contract basically said that they can spy on me
- I am not allowed to open the laptop or replace parts

Assumption: The Laptop physically cannot connect to Wifi without replacing the wifi card (or inserting one for the first time)

It can, for some reason, use the bluetooth hotspot from my iPhone to access the internet. However, it is very inconvenient having to switch the SIM card from my mobile router, which creates the Wifi network all my devices use, into my phone, just to share it with my ThinkPad L420. So, I want to be able to take the Wifi network that comes into my Asus ROG G751JY Laptop, and create a bluetooth hotspot, like my iPhone does, so that I can share it with my ThinkPad L420 (so that I can actually use the computer to do anything that requires online research).

But when I go into the wifi settings, it tells me:
[image]

Is it possible to feed a computer with Wifi and it spits out internet-bluetooth?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Blueman Bluetooth manager can create a Bluetooth internet connection